# Explain how $(p \land \lnot q) \iff (\lnot p \lor q)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, equivalence-relations

Is this DeMorgan's law?

I know DeMorgan's law in the form of

$\lnot(p \land q) \iff \lnot p \lor \lnot q$

and

$\lnot(p \lor q) \iff \lnot p \land \lnot q$

But I cannot conceptualize it in the form of

$p \land \lnot q) \iff (\lnot p \lor q)$

Comment: You can't because it's false..

Comment: those are literally negations, so you have $T\iff F$ for any combination of values of $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: Did you perhaps intend $\lnot(p \land \lnot q) \iff (\lnot p \lor q)$ or $(p \land \lnot q) \iff \lnot(\lnot p \lor q)$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. If you construct the truth table for these, you get:
$$\begin{array}{cc|cc|cc}
p & q & \neg p & \neg q & p \wedge \neg q & \neg p \vee q\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0& 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1& 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0& 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0& 1\\
\end{array}$$
So they are not equivalent (the columns should be identical), but in fact they are opposites: $p \wedge \neg q \iff \neg (\neg p \vee q)$.

If you want to prove this last thing, the truth table is pretty clear about that, but you can also use the second De Morgan's law you posted:
$$\neg (p \vee q) \iff \neg p \wedge \neg q$$
And now replace $p$ by $\neg p$:
$$\neg (\neg p \vee q) \iff \neg (\neg p) \wedge \neg q$$
And since $\neg(\neg p) \iff p$, you obtain
$$\neg (\neg p \vee q) \iff p \wedge \neg q$$